# version info not a dictionary : chromeDriver : chrome 21

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a test using webdriver on chrome. I am getting this error message.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: version info not a dictionary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16.84 seconds
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

The version details are :
Chrome 21.0.1180.60
selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0
ChromeDriver 22,29,0.8 (I've tried with all three versions and getting errors).

My code is as below:

public class Testing {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "E://eclipse_workspace//testSelPro//lib//chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(
                        new File(
                                "E://eclipse_workspace//testSelPro//lib//chromedriver.exe"))
                .usingAnyFreePort().build();
        service.start();
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, capability);

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
                    driver.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

I have a limitation of running the scripts on Chrome 21 only as application is required to be certified on the same version. Also, I do not have the liberty to move to older versions of selenium as other application(s) require latest webdriver version on the framework.

Comment: You'll need to downgrade the ChromeDriver then. If you can only run Chrome v21 then you can only run the lower and older versions of ChromeDriver.

Comment: Your selenium version is old. The latest one as of today is 2.40